# enumerate and zip within Coffeescript?

Tags: list-comprehension, coffeescript

Coming from Python, I like many of the features that Coffeescript borrows from Python and Perl (ranges/slices, comprehensions, destructuring assignments). Is there any syntactic sugar in Coffeescript to mimic Python's `enumerate` or `zip` (`itertools.izip`) functions?

Here are the patterns that I don't care much for:

```
# an enumerate call would be helpful here
i = 0
for x in arr
  ... use x and i ...
  i++
```

and

```
# a zip would be useful here
n = Math.min(arr1.length,arr2.length)
for i in 0...n
  x = arr1[i]; y = arr2[i]
  ... use x and y ...
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

forEach is effectively built in:

```
a = ['a','b','c']
for el,i in a
    alert "Element #{el} is at index #{i}"
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I knew this once, but it was so simple that I forgot it.

Comment: I actually checked the [language reference](http://CoffeeScript.Org/#loops) before I wrote my answer but this doesn't seem to be documented, or more likely, I didn't find it.

Comment: It's the last answer in the [FAQ](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/FAQ), but I don't think there's an explicit example anywhere else.

Comment: I found this by accident, playing around with the syntax. Then I checked the website, but couldn't find anything about it and started to wonder if this is officially acknowledged and supported.

Comment: isn't it supposed to be `of` for object iteration?

Comment: And you parameters are backwards. index, element

Answer (score 13):

Enumerate:

```
arr.forEach (x, i) ->
    ... use x and i ...
```

`zip` / `zipWith` (I learned these from Haskell; I assume they mean the same thing in Python?):

```
zip = (arr1, arr2) ->
  basic_zip = (el1, el2) -> [el1, el2]
  zipWith basic_zip, arr1, arr2

zipWith = (func, arr1, arr2) ->
  min = Math.min arr1.length, arr2.length
  ret = []

  for i in [0...min]
    ret.push func(arr1[i], arr2[i])

  ret
```

Some examples (tested):

```
zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])          # => [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]

add = (el1, el2) -> el1 + el2
zipWith(add, [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]) # => [5, 7, 9]
```

---

**Update**: Reimplemented Haskell-style, just for fun. Not as cool without the pattern matching, but oh well..

```
zipWith = (func, arr1, arr2) ->
  return [] if arr1.length is 0 or arr2.length is 0

  el1 = arr1.shift()
  el2 = arr2.shift()

  ret_arr = zipWith func, arr1, arr2
  ret_arr.unshift func(el1, el2)

  ret_arr
```

Oh, man, this was fun. SO needs more questions like this :D

[Gist for `zip` and `zipWith`](https://gist.github.com/914939)

Comment: Thanks for the zipWith implementations. I'll keep them handy for node.js code.

Answer (score 8):

For zipping and other such utility functions, [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) is pretty much the standard library—and it happens to have been created by Jeremy Ashkenas, the man behind CoffeeScript. With it, you could write your zip example as

```
for elems in _.zip(arr1, arr2)
  x = elems[0]; y = elems[1]
  ...
```

or better yet

```
for [x, y] in _.zip(arr1, arr2)
  ...
```

using pattern-matching. Note, however, that `_.zip` uses the *max* length of `arr1` and `arr2`, not the min; so if you don't want to handle `undefined` values, you should truncate the longer array first.

There's also a CoffeeScript implementation of Underscore, [Underscore.coffee](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/documentation/docs/underscore.html), which is a great place to look if you're wondering how to implement a particular loop in CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 5):

[The CoffeeScript Cookbook](http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/) lists a nice implementation of a zip function:

```
# Usage: zip(arr1, arr2, arr3, ...)
zip = () ->
  lengthArray = (arr.length for arr in arguments)
  length = Math.min(lengthArray...)
  for i in [0...length]
    arr[i] for arr in arguments

zip([0, 1, 2, 3], [0, -1, -2, -3])
# => [[0, 0], [1, -1], [2, -2], [3, -3]]
```

http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/arrays/zip-function

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that CoffeeScript is just an alternate syntax for ECMAScript. At least for your first example, there is a perfectly good ECMAscript function ([`Array.prototype.forEach`](http://ES5.GitHub.Com/#x15.4.4.18)), which already does what you want:

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c"]

arr.forEach (el, i) ->
  alert "Element #{el} is at index #{i}"
```

Unfortunately, there is no `Array.prototype.zip` or `Array.prototype.zipWith`. That seems to be a pretty big omission, especially considering that there is both `reduce` and `reduceRight`, the latter of which many other languages don't have. My guess is that it is a simple oversight, and we are going to see `zip` in some future version of the language.

Answer (score 0):

For zip, try this one:

```coffee
zip = (x...) ->
  (y[i] for y in x for i in [0...Math.min (y.length for y in x)...])
```

If you prefer to zip all the way to the end, use `Math.max()`.